# Drawing a constant randomly distorted circle

Tags: tikz-pgf, random-numbers, random

I am trying to draw a special and contradictive plot : A circle with random distortions which have to remain constant regardless of how many times I build the document.

An example of what I am trying to achieve can be seen below

[image]

This figure was produced with the following code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}   
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        % axes
        \draw[ultra thin] (-2.5, 0) -- (2.5, 0);
        \draw[ultra thin] (0, -2.5) -- (0, 2.5);
        % undistorted sphere
        \draw[ultra thin, dashed] (0, 0) circle (2.25cm);
        \draw[ultra thin, dashed, ->] (0:0) -- (125:2.25);
        \node at (-1, 1) {$R$};
        % distrorted sphere
        \draw[very thick] plot[domain=0:350,smooth cycle ] (\x:2+rnd*0.5);
        \draw[very thick, ->] (0:0) -- (45:2.1);
        \draw[ultra thin, ->] (1, 0) arc (0:45:1);
        \node at (1.2, 0.4) {$\theta$};
        \node at (0.7, 1.25) {$R(\theta)$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The problem with the code is that whenever I make a change to it and rebuild the document, the "distorted" circle will have a different shape, since I am using the `rnd` function. The reason I would like to have a constant-random shape is because I would like to denote its radius at an angle θ, therefore it has to touch the outline of the circle.

Any idea on how to achieve such a thing?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In answer by user [JPG](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/77557/jpg), the vector `R` don't intersect with randomize curve. For achieving the intersecting of two path, we have to use the `intersections` library. Adding to JPG's answer:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}   
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,intersections}

    \begin{document}
       \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
            \pgfmathsetseed{1} % choose a number which give a good shape to your circle
            % axes
            \draw[ultra thin] (-2.5, 0) -- (2.5, 0);
            \draw[ultra thin] (0, -2.5) -- (0, 2.5);
            % undistorted sphere
            \draw[ultra thin, dashed] (0, 0) circle (2.25cm);
            \draw[ultra thin, dashed, ->] (0:0) -- (125:2.25);
            \node at (-1, 1) {$R$};
            % distrorted sphere
            \path[draw,very thick, name path=curve] plot[domain=0:350,smooth cycle ] (\x:2+rnd*0.5);
            \path[very thick, name path=line] (0:0) -- (45:2.5);
            \draw [name intersections={of=curve and  line, by=x}];
            \draw [very thick, ->] (0,0)--(x);
            \draw[ultra thin, ->] (1, 0) arc (0:45:1);
            \node at (1.2, 0.4) {$\theta$};
            \node at (0.7, 1.25) {$R(\theta)$};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: With this elegant solution, we don't need the fixed random seed from the first answer anymore.

Comment: @Thanos, your welcome.  Also, You may thick the JPG's answer.

Comment: @ferahfeza : I know, but I believe your answer is more complete!

Comment: how to shift to (-2,0) ?

Answer (score 15):

Use `\pgfmathsetseed` to initialize the seed for random number generation:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}   
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}


\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pgfmathsetseed{1} % choose a number which give a good shape to your circle
        % axes
        \draw[ultra thin] (-2.5, 0) -- (2.5, 0);
        \draw[ultra thin] (0, -2.5) -- (0, 2.5);
        % undistorted sphere
        \draw[ultra thin, dashed] (0, 0) circle (2.25cm);
        \draw[ultra thin, dashed, ->] (0:0) -- (125:2.25);
        \node at (-1, 1) {$R$};
        % distrorted sphere
        \draw[very thick] plot[domain=0:350,smooth cycle ] (\x:2+rnd*0.5);
        \draw[very thick, ->] (0:0) -- (45:2.1);
        \draw[ultra thin, ->] (1, 0) arc (0:45:1);
        \node at (1.2, 0.4) {$\theta$};
        \node at (0.7, 1.25) {$R(\theta)$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT: if you want the length of the arrow to be computed automatically**

Then you can generate the length of the arrow before the plot, and use this length for the exact angle you want. Since you do not know on which angles the plot will be computed, you should start the plot at the angle you want to draw your arrow:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}   
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pgfmathsetseed{1}
        % axes
        \draw[ultra thin] (-2.5, 0) -- (2.5, 0);
        \draw[ultra thin] (0, -2.5) -- (0, 2.5);
        % undistorted sphere
        \draw[ultra thin, dashed] (0, 0) circle (2.25cm);
        \draw[ultra thin, dashed, ->] (0:0) -- (125:2.25);
        \node at (-1, 1) {$R$};
        % distrorted sphere
        \pgfmathsetmacro\RR{2+rnd*0.5}
        \draw[very thick] plot[domain=45:395,smooth cycle ] (\x:{ifthenelse(\x==45,\RR,2+rnd*0.5)});
        \draw[very thick, ->] (0:0) -- (45:\RR);
        \draw[ultra thin, ->] (1, 0) arc (0:45:1);
        \node at (1.2, 0.4) {$\theta$};
        \node at (0.7, 1.25) {$R(\theta)$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: While we get a reproducible (not changing) random cyclic path on very compilation, it requires the thick arrow denoting the current radius to be adjusted manually.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I wish I could select you answer. Keep up!!!

Comment: @AlexG I updated my answer to have the arrow length adjusted automatically.

Comment: You could also do `\draw[very thick] plot[domain=55:405,smooth cycle ] 
  (\x:{2+rnd*0.5});
  \pgfgetlastxy{\myx}{\myy}
        \draw[very thick, ->] (0:0) -- (\myx,\myy);` in order to get rid of the `ifthenelse`. (The reason why I am suggesting that is that the comparison may fail in a plot.)